# Not able to identify the element in a DOM for buttons

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I am using robot framework and have the below DOM:-

```
<div class="fancybox-inner" style="overflow: hidden; width: 940px; height: 635px;"><iframe id="fancybox-frame1664438391177" name="fancybox-frame1664438391177" class="fancybox-iframe" frameborder="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="" scrolling="auto" src="StartWizard.do?wparam_wizard_name=CustomCreateOrganization"></iframe>
<div class="wizardFooter">
  <div id="wizardButtons" class="wizardButtons">
    <input type="button" value="Reload" style="display:none">
    <input type="button" class="btn alignleft marginrightmini" onclick="disableButton(this);submitForm('wizardForm','back','back','wizardForm');" disabled="true" value="Previous"> 
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary alignleft marginrightmini" onclick="disableButton(this);submitForm('wizardForm','next','next','wizardForm');" value="Next"> 
    <input type="button" class="btn alignleft marginrightmini" onclick="disableButton(this);submitForm('wizardForm','finish','finish','wizardForm','1ooqrvebnfv5ff2fcoe6raulan');" disabled="true" value="Done">
    <input type="button" class="btn alignright" onclick="disableButton(this);submitForm('wizardForm','org.apache.struts.taglib.html.CANCEL','org.apache.struts.taglib.html.CANCEL','wizardForm');" value="Cancel">
  <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am not able to identify the next button using the below options:-

```
Click Element //*[@id="wizardButtons"]/input[3]
Click Element //*[contains(text(),'Next')]
```

Please help me with the same.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
//div[@class='wizardButtons']//input[@value='Next']
```

According to a comment, the HTML markup is inside an iframe, which was not mentioned in the question. If that's the case, and assuming you're using SeleniumLibrary, you must select the frame with [Select Frame](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Select%20Frame) before you can interact with it

```
Select frame   //iframe[@id="jspContentIframe"]
Click element  //div[@class='wizardButtons']//input[@value='Next']
```

Comment: 21:42:36.261 FAIL Element with locator 'xpath://div[@class='wizardButtons']//input[@value='Next']' not found.

Comment: FAIL Element with locator '//div[@class='wizardButtons']//input[@value='Next']' not found.

Comment: @navaldogra: this works for me when I try it on the markup in the question.  Is there more that we don't know? For example, is this html inside of an iframe?

Comment: Sorry to mention that, everything is under the iframe "<iframe _ngcontent-dqk-17="" frameborder="0" height="100%" id="jspContentIframe" name="jspWrapperFrame" width="100%" src="index.do">Browser not compatible.</iframe>"

Comment: @navaldogra: you need to update your original question with that crucial piece of information.

Comment: updated as per your comment @Bryan